# ZipArchive Produces empty ZIP file

Tags: c#, stream, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to create a ZipArchive in memory and append several entries with binary data from database. The problem is that after loop, zip sent to client is invalid/empty. Can you please check my code?

```
using (MemoryStream _memory_stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive _archive = new ZipArchive(_memory_stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (byte[] binaryData in this.FileBinaries)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry _entry = _archive.CreateEntry(str_filename, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            
            using (Stream _entryStream = _entry.Open()) 
            {
                using (StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(_entryStream))
                {
                    _writer.Write(binaryData);
                    
                }
                _entryStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=certificates.zip");
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.Write(_memory_stream);
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid burning the memory; stream the zip instead https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html

Comment: `Response.Write` doesn't accept a `Stream`, so it probably doesn't understand `_memory_stream` anyway. You should refactor to write directly to `Response.OutputStream`.

Comment: Hi. I used Response.OutputStream.Write() as you suggested and the zip file came valid, yet still empty. Can you see some problem when creating the entries in the ZipArchive?

Comment: Maybe set position to 0 on _memory_stream_ before esponse.Write(.

Comment: `ZipArchive _archive = new ZipArchive(_memory_stream,` -> `ZipArchive _archive = new ZipArchive(response.OutputStream` ... and set the header and content type BEFORE your ZipArchive code. Remove the `MemoryStream` altogether.